# ASP.NET MVC 2 Form Not Passing Values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a strange problem happening today.  I am running the latest version of the MVC V2 framework and have been having no trouble at all - I came in this morning and for some reason values aren't being passed in to actions.

To clarify lets say I have something like this:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Registration", FormMethod.Post)) { %>
....
<input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Register" />
<% } %>
```

And in my controller I have the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegistrationModel model, string register)
{
      // At this point the register string is null
}
```

This has been working fine for a while now and I have not changed anything that I can think of that would cause this to happen.

Does that make sense and as anyone any idea what is going on or what I have messed up?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your view strongly typed?  Also, it looks like your register value can only come across as "Register", or am I missing something?

Comment: The view is strongly typed yes. The submit button is called 'register' with a lower case r, the only upper case R is the value which is what the button displays as it's text.

Answer (score 1):

"Not changed anything", Well most of the time code doesn't work differently just because its Friday instead of Thursday.

" I can think of that would cause"

So you changed something, undo those changes one by one and see what happens.

Something must have changed.  Do you have a custom model binder that you were working on?  Did you add a route that may catch the one your posting too?

Comment: I have seen plenty of situations where an apparently unrelated change can be the cause of a problem.  +1 for backing out some recent changes and see what happens.

Comment: No code changes have been made at all - what I have been working on is changing the theme - so in that respect the ONLY thing that has changed are CSS files. How would that effect the form submits?

Comment: I don't know what to say then.  Code just doesn't turn off.  You changed something, maybe you don't remember.  Post the html output that your using.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I really hadn't made any code changes. It was indeed the theme that I was using for the site. Long story short it came with a JavaScript file to various things and tucked away at the bottom of the file was a function to skin the buttons - once I had removed that line it worked just fine.

Comment: Two things I've discovered.  1.  Can't use this method for image buttons (which is why the skin broke it).  2.  Must have the 'name' attribute of the button set.